# Hide/Unhide merged cells in excel

Tags: excel, vba

So on excel I have 2 worksheets one called **Setup** and the other called **Summary**. The user is asked to fill out questionnaire from the "**Setup**" worksheet. Information filled out in the setup page copies over to the Summary page. Below are 2 pictures showing the Setup page and Summary page.

**Setup Page**

[image: ![enter image description here]

**Summary page**

[image]

So the issue I am having is that I am trying to automate the hide/unhide feature using vba and its not working for merged cells. I want the Summary page to hide **Rows 33 to 35** if the setup page is left blank and unhide if something is written on the Setup page. Here is the code I have tried below and got this run-time error.

```
    Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)

     With Sheets("Setup")
            If Range("M29").value = False Then
            Sheets("SUMMARY").Range("B33:B35").Hidden = False
            Else
            Sheets("SUMMARY").Range("B33:B35").Hidden = True
            End If
     End With
   End Sub
```

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instead of `Range`, use `Rows`.

```
Sheets("SUMMARY").Rows("33:35").Hidden = False 'and similarly for True
```

Also, note that you're not actually referencing the `With`. You need a period `.` before `Range`.

```
With Sheets("Setup")
    If .Range("M29").value = False Then
```

You may be looking for `IsEmpty` to test if that range is blank.

Also, if this code is in the "Setup" sheet code module, then you can use `Me` instead of `Sheets("Setup")`.

With those edits, you might have something like this:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)

    If IsEmpty(Me.Range("M29").Value) Then
        Sheets("SUMMARY").Rows("33:35").Hidden = True ' shouldn't this be True, hide if empty?
    Else
        Sheets("SUMMARY").Rows("33:35").Hidden = False
    End If

End Sub
```

Or as a one-liner:

```
  Sheets("SUMMARY").Rows("33:35").Hidden = IsEmpty(Me.Range("M29").Value)
```